# jsPDF Salto de Página

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Buenas estoy usando este plugins

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1
/jspdf.min.js">
</script>
```

(jsPDF) que es básicamente un script que convierte html a pdf, con esto leo datos contenidos dentro de un div con id content y luego lo guardo a pdf con el siguinte código

```
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    $('#cmd').click(function () {   
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('Usuarios_en_linea.pdf');
});
</script>
```

Sé que para darle un salto de pagina debo utilizar `doc.addPage();` pero estoy medio perdido en como agregar al script el salto de linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucione el inconveniente cambiando la versión del plugins y algunos detalles ahora ya se pagina automáticamente

```
<button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">Generate PDF</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {  
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

        source = $('#content')[0];

        specialElementHandlers = {
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        pdf.fromHTML(
        source, 
        margins.left, 
        margins.top, { 
            'width': margins.width,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },

        function (dispose) {
            pdf.save('Estadistica.pdf');
        }, margins);
    };
</script>
```