# jspdf No pagina correctamente

Tags: php, html, jspdf

Tengo una tabla con bastantes filas (php y html). Al momento de descargar la tabla (usando jspdf), en el pdf se corta la información en vez de pasar a la siguiente página.

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?,

He intentado con pdf.addpage(); pero no es lo que estoy buscando, este es mi script

```
<script>
    function pruebaDivAPdf() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

        pdf.setFont("helvetica");
        pdf.setFontType("bold");
        pdf.setFontSize(9);
        
        source = $('#imprimir')[0];

        specialElementHandlers = {
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 50,
            //bottom: 60,
            left: 60,
            //: 1000
        };

        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, 
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, 
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                pdf.save('Constancia.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
</script>
```

y así se genera el pdf:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no quieres agregar páginas con `addPage()` para generar una paginación entonces qué es lo qué estás buscando?

Comment: lo que sucede es que agregué addPage(); pero se creó una página en blanco al inicio, y la siguiente página era la misma vista con la tabla cortada :(

Comment: jsPDF lamentablemente no genera paginación automática, el espacio en blanco es porque no estás agregando nada nuevo a la página, hay qué pensar un algoritmo de paginación.

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193716/jspdf-salto-de-p%C3%A1gina) está la respuesta que buscaba